# Whitespace at the end of jar name fails DLL to load

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file which contains code to read DLL files. If I put a whitespace at the end of jar filename, the jar file is not considered as part of the classpath resulting in not loading the DLL files. What can be done?
Can we not have whitespaces in a jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside whether it's good practise to have a whitespace at the *end* of your jarfile name (I would *strongly* suggest not - it's going to cause chaos), you should be able to set your `CLASSPATH` appropriately, but it must be quoted appropriately e.g.

```
CLASSPATH="myjarwithafollowingspace.jar :otherjarfile.jar"
```

i.e. note the classpath is quoted appropriately. If it's the last entry on your classpath, you'd have:

```
CLASSPATH="originajarfile.jar:myjarwithafollowingspace.jar "
```

and quoting the `-cp` on the command line would work similarly.

Comment: I get this issue even if it is named as "jarname (1).jar"

Comment: You should be able to escape in exactly the same way

Comment: can you please explain what will change in terms of classloading when we have a jarname with spaces??

Comment: If the JVM can find/load the jar, then nothing at all. Classes should be loaded regardless of the jar name, provided that file can be successfully found/loaded